# Bitcoin Core 0.15 reindexing blockchain looks like its hanging?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

and run bitcoind and bitcoin-cli from source so i can start messing around with some of the api calls and hopefully develop some cool stuff.
Unfortuantely running bitcoind says i must reindex the blockchain as i'm building over the top of a previous corrupted blockchain.
Running the call:

bitcoind -reindex -daemon -printtoconsole

I get:

```
2017-09-17 15:11:12 Bitcoin version v0.15.99.0-e278f86c5 
2017-09-17 15:11:12 InitParameterInteraction: parameter interaction: -whitelistforcerelay=1 -> setting -whitelistrelay=1 
2017-09-17 15:11:12 Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000003b9ce759c2a087d52abc4266f8f4ebd6d768b89defa50a have valid signatures. 
2017-09-17 15:11:12 Setting nMinimumChainWork=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000723d3581fe1bd55373540a 
2017-09-17 15:11:12 Using the 'sse4' SHA256 implementation 
2017-09-17 15:11:12 Using RdRand as an additional entropy source Bitcoin server starting
```

With nothing ever progressing past Bitcoin Server starting. Then when i run:

bitcoin-cli getinfo

error code: -32601

error message: Method not found

The process is still running correctly and i can't rerun bitcoind as i've got the process already running in the background. Does anyone have any ideas ?

UPDATE:
When i tail the log i now get

```
2017-09-17 15:10:46 Reindexing block file blk00076.dat... 
2017-09-17 15:10:47 tor: Thread interrupt 
2017-09-17 15:10:47 torcontrol thread exit 
2017-09-17 15:10:47 net thread exit 
2017-09-17 15:10:47 addcon thread exit 
2017-09-17 15:10:47 opencon thread exit 
2017-09-17 15:10:47 msghand thread exit 
2017-09-17 15:10:47 scheduler thread interrupt 
2017-09-17 15:10:47 Shutdown: In progress... 
2017-09-17 15:10:50 Shutdown: done
```

Is there a reason the node is automatically shutting down as i haven't authorised any shutdown commands ? Is there a way to check?

UPDATE2:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/eb0d26892161f2b25933917d1d89c139

Left it running again using -reindex and no -printtoconsole still as a daemon. 
Trying to interpret the above log, looks like i'm all up and running ? Is there a way to check and next time i start the bitcoind process i do it without a -reindex ?

Comment: Can you post more of the log (stuff before this snippet)?

Comment: Only ever pass -reindex once. If you shutdown, and restart, it will continue where it left off. If you start with -reindex again, it will start over.

Answer (score 2):

> bitcoin-cli getinfo

The `getinfo` RPC has been removed in the master branch (which is what you are using). Try using a different RPC like `getblockchaininfo` or `getnetworkinfo`. The fact that you are getting a response with `Method not found` indicates that the RPC server is up and running, so the node should be working.

I don't think `-daemon` and `-printtoconsole` interact well so you may not actually see the debug lines.

Comment: When i tail the log i now get
 2017-09-17 15:10:46 Reindexing block file blk00076.dat... 2017-09-17 15:10:47 tor: Thread interrupt 2017-09-17 15:10:47 torcontrol thread exit 2017-09-17 15:10:47 net thread exit 2017-09-17 15:10:47 addcon thread exit 2017-09-17 15:10:47 opencon thread exit 2017-09-17 15:10:47 msghand thread exit 2017-09-17 15:10:47 scheduler thread interrupt 2017-09-17 15:10:47 Shutdown: In progress... 2017-09-17 15:10:50 Shutdown: done

Is there a reason the node is automatically shutting down as i haven't authorised any shutdown commands ? Is there a way to check?

Comment: Can you post the full log as an edit to your question and format properly in code blocks?